# connection state is closed when using a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, sqlconnection

I'm trying to use a `Using()` statement with a `SqlConnection`.

I've made the `SqlConnection` a page property like so...

```
public SqlConnection baseConnection
{
    get { return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }
}
```

then created the `using()` statement like so...

```
using (baseConnection)
            {
                SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", baseConnection);
                baseConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

                //... other irrelevant code
            }
```

But when the code runs I get an exception

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

I understand the exception, what I dont understand, is why is the connection not open when I've opened it with `baseConnection.Open()` ?

I use this connection all over the site, and I'd like to put it in a custom base class as a page property so I don't have to keep typing it. Is this not allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem I find in your example**

> You get new SqlConnection object each time you request *baseConnection* property

**Problematic code:**

```
public SqlConnection baseConnection
{
    get { return new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }
}
```

**Corrected Code**

```
private SqlConnection _baseConnection;
public SqlConnection BaseConnection
{
    get { return _baseConnection = _baseConnection ?? new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString); }
}
```

Here `return _baseConnection = _baseConnection ?? new SqlConnection()` is using Null Coaleasing operator from C# `??` i.e. It will create new instance if `_baseConnection` variable is null.

**My Assumptions**
`BaseConnection` property is defined in some `BaseClass` and derived class is not extended further in sub-derived class. And in this way you would have one SqlConnection in use per derived class types.

Comment: @Aniket : because the baseConnection attached to the selectCommand is not the one which gets opened

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea. calling `Dispose` on a connection does not make it `null`. therfore this will only works once (then it is created) and fail the rest of the time.

Comment: Man, I didn't see that because the property is named like a local variable! Use proper naming (uppercase).

Comment: @usr that is where I got confused too - did not see it was a property - more like a local variable

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've not been coding c# for long. I've updated my property name like `BaseConnection` and applied this answer. It works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be :

```
using (var myConnection = baseConnection)
            {
                SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE", myConnection );
                myConnection .Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();

                //... other irrelevant code
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   string sQry = "Select * from TestEmp"; // Select Table
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQry, conDB);// Pass Sql Query & Sql Connection in Sql Command
   conDB.Open();// Open DB
   SqlDataAdapter objAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); // Create DisConnected Architecture
   DataTable objTable = new DataTable(); // Create Data Table
   objAdapter.Fill(objTable);// Fill Data Table using Adapter Object
   dgvDisplay.DataSource = objTable; // Display select result in DataGridView Box
   conDB.Close(); // Close Connection
```